# template argument deduction/substitution failed:

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Непонимаю, почему не может определить тип автоматически.
Наверное потому что передаю не тип, а значение.

Как быть??

```
template <typename T>
Params ToParams ( const Where& where, std::pair<std::string, T> var )
{
     Params params = ToParams ( where );
     params.insert( { var.first, ToString( var.second ) });
     return params;
}
```

```
foo( const Where& where, const std::string& mask, std::string& msg )
{
    Params params = ToParams( where , { std::string( "mask" ), mask } ); // fail
    // Params params = ToParams<std::string>( where , { std::string( "mask" ), mask } ); // ok
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что

```
{ std::string( "mask" ), mask }
```

это `initializer_list`, а не `pair`... Вот так должно пройти:

```
Params params = ToParams( where , make_pair(std::string( "mask" ), mask) );
```

потому что будет явно показан тип.